# Inconsistencies with && and divide-by-zero error in Java

Tags: java, logic

I'm starting out Java, and I am experiencing some inconsistencies.  Why does this work:

```
if ((d != 0) && (n / d < 3)) {
    compute(a, d);
}
```

But if I do this:

```
if ((n / d < 3) && (d != 0)) {
    compute(a, d);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at compute.main(compute.java:63)
```

Comment: Voted to close, as you do seem to think that it is unimportant to us what exact error you get and from where.

Comment: I added the error message, is this better?

Comment: +1 for adding the error message.

Comment: No longer a candidate for closing due to the edits. @Ingo I recommend in the future posting your criticism first and giving them a chance to fix it before voting to close so hastily.

Comment: Thanks for allowing me to redeem myself lol

Comment: @user2512229 Next time you'll be executed ;)

Comment: Challenge: pick an more apropos title now that there's better understanding..

Answer (score 23):

Java evaluates expressions using [Short-Circuit Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  What this means is that for `&&`, if the left expression is `false`, then Java does not bother evaluating the right expression (since the whole expression is guaranteed to be false already).

In your first example, if `d == 0`, then `d != 0` is false, so it will not evaluate `n / d`.  In your second example, if `d == 0`, then evaluating `n / d < 3` will give you the divide by zero error.

Comment: Additionally: This "short-circuit" behaviour is not specific to Java - it is supported in most programming languages.

Comment: See also the Java language specification: [Conditional-And Operator &&](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) - The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.

Comment: Wow, this really clarifies!

Comment: The same applies for ||. If the left-hand operand is true, it won't evaluate the right one.

Comment: Obscure language note: short-circuiting does NOT happen for & and |.

Answer (score 5):

In your first example, because of [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), when `d == 0`, the compiler figures out it doesn't need to evaluate `n/d`, since `false && true` would still be false.

If you turn the conditions around, you end up evaluating `n/d` first, before knowing if d is zero. What you cause is an error because of a division by zero.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an inconsistency.  Any language derived from the C language (C++, Java, many others) behaves this way (short circuits the && and || operators).

If you want both sides evaluated, use & and | (vs && and ||).